# Pipe subprocess of nmap out into variable, and awk it for a specific mac addr

Tags: python

So I have this neat command I found that scans my network to find Raspberry Pi's hence the awk with the specific mac address, and I want to run it inside of my python script however I can't seem to get it to work no matter how many ' or " or () I use it still tells me I have invalid syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my script

```
import os
import shlex
import subprocess

class FindPi:

  def __init__(self, ip):
    self.ip = ip

  def nmap_awk_results(self):
    cmd = 'sudo nmap -sP 172.16.4.*/24 "|" awk /^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print "Found a Raspberry PI @" ip}'

    s = shlex.split(cmd)
    fff = subprocess.check_output(s) #Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    #out = fff.stdout.read()
    print fff


FindPi('172.16.4.*/24').nmap_awk_results()

***after fixing the string I get a new error now how ever the nmap part works***

Failed to resolve "|".
Failed to resolve "awk".
Unable to split netmask from target expression: "/^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print"
Failed to resolve "Found a Raspberry PI @".
Failed to resolve "ip}".
```

I know my command works cause of this result

[image: Test Pic]

Comment: You need to escape the quotes in your command. See, for example, [these](https://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex10.html) [links](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

Comment: I tried that     cmd = 'sudo nmap -sP 172.16.4.*/24 "|" awk /^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print "Found a Raspberry PI @" ip}'

Comment: Failed to resolve "|".
Failed to resolve "awk".
Unable to split netmask from target expression: "/^Nmap/{ip=$NF}/B8:27:EB/{print"
Failed to resolve "Found a Raspberry PI @".
Failed to resolve "ip}".

Comment: I get the above error now ^ @glibdud